# Is it safe to change permissions for /usr/share folder?

Tags: themes, permissions, files

These days I mess around with files in `/usr/share` folder, like modify themes and other stuff... So, is it safe to change permissions of `/usr/share` folder so I don't have to open it as root every time I want to change something there? Or at least just `/usr/share/themes` folder?

Answer (score 5):

If you are the only user on your system changing permission `/usr/share/themes` should be safe. But it's usually a better idea to use your home folder for the files you are working on. Just put your themes in `$HOME/.themes/` (create the folder if it doesn't exist), you can use them from there, too.